# Report Viewer Configuration Error at one report only

Tags: ssrs-2008

While creating an `SSRS report` I am getting this error at run time( that too I had to find out using page view source as it was hidden )

[image: Check ERROR]

I have many SSRS reports in my application and all others are being rendered well, I created a new one in a similar manner but faced this issue. 
My `web.config` file already has these entries.

Can someone please help ??

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing your error, you have to add the Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handle for your application. Please take the following steps:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand Sites node and select your site.
3. Double click Handler Mappings feature.
4. Click Add Managed Handler in the Actions Pane to add the handler.

Comment: But then why is it working for other reports in the same application?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem caused by an error in how I called the Reports method. The reportViewer Web control is in a hidden field and I forgot to assign the report to the hidden field's value when I called it.

The page source:

```
<body onload="Doload();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" EnableViewState="True">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
</form>
```

This call gave the error because the report was not assigned to the value.

```
Reports.MyReport (ref this.ReportViewer1, this.Request["Field2"]);
```

Assigning its value to the hidden field rendered it like all the other reports.

```
HiddenField1.Value = Reports.MyReport (ref this.ReportViewer1, this.Request["Field2"]);
```

The wording of the error message sent me looking in the wrong place.